# Cannot set focus on input text type in TinyMCE in Google Chrome

Tags: java, jquery, google-chrome, tinymce-4

i cannot set focus on textbox when I click on it,only on google chrome... I also wrote an event that when I click on textbox it should focus on them.

Comment: Can you show some example? Piece of code?

Comment: I resolved it by enabling event preventdefault and setting focus on selected textbox